# What is a DBA's definition of "batch"?

Tags: sqlite, terminology

I've heard it being used in relation to SQLite sometimes but never completely understood what it means.

Answer (score 4):

A batch is a series of SQL commands that are sent to the database server at once. This can be faster than sending each command individually because there is less network communication.

SQLite is an embedded database; SQL commands are executed directly by the SQLite library.
There is no separate server, so it would not make sense to have batches. SQLite does not have such batches.

---

Another meaning of "batch" might be the multi-row form of the INSERT command:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'this'), (2, 'that'), (3, 'whatever');
```

Answer (score 2):

"Batch" is typically a verb, though it may also be a noun. Oftentimes, the technical term for the result of batching is a *"transaction."* And, more often then not, "batching" is to get around excessive commits with rollback points, or the need to cache or lock for a very long modification.

If used in the context outside of writes to a database, it can be said that you're batching "jobs" (as the units of work inside a batch). However, in the database the unit of work is normally a [DML Statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) and those are never referred to as jobs.

For more information see also [Batch Processing (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing)

Answer (score 0):

A group of one or more TSQL commands, such as SELECT or UPDATE, together can form a batch. `GO` SSMS instruction is used to indicate the end of a batch hence has a role of a separator. You can use multiple `GO`s to split the statements into multiple batches. Batches are useful during compilation time because SQL Server considers a batch a single unit and assigns a single execution plan to each batch. Batch differs from transaction because its statements are executed separately though they are the same execution plan. So if you have two batches, even if there is an error in the first batch the second batch is going to be execute. Note that both the batch itself and the GO command are not part of the TSQL instead they are useful facilities of SSMS.

Comment: This is an answer when working with Microsoft SQL Server  and as such is only slightly relevant for OP. The question is asking for an answer related to SQLite.

Answer (score -3):

The word "batch" as indicates executing the batch of commands to database at once instead of executing multiple queries one by one. This helps in avoiding the multiple network calls to the database from the application.

Using stored procs is one of such good example to batch execute the commands. This helps the [DBM](https://fullformfactory.com/dbm-full-form/) to run the queries faster without any issues.